# where can I put my EditTexts so they stop giving me a nullpointer exception error?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext

I don't have any errors in my project but when I run it, it closes straight away, giving a nullpointer exception error with these lines :

```
EditText nameofcontact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextname);
EditText numberofcontact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextname);
```

I think I get why this error is happening – the Edittexts are being mentioned before they even exist, but when I put them in the onCreate my code still doesn't work. (It gives me  problems with my nameofcontact and numberofcontact variables in my createbutton).

Any ideas ? Where should I put these lines so my project will function correctly or what code should I add? Thanks for any help.

```
package com.example.chris.addnewcontact;

import android.content.ContentProviderOperation;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.OperationApplicationException;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public String contactname;
public String contactnumber;

//the lines below are giving me null pointer exception error.

EditText nameofcontact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextname);
EditText numberofcontact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextname);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createButton);


}

public void createButton(View view) {

contactname = nameofcontact.getText().toString();
contactnumber = numberofcontact.getText().toString();

Log.d("test","yes, button is working");
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> contentProviderOperations = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
//insert raw contact using RawContacts.CONTENT_URI
contentProviderOperations.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
.withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null).withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null).build());
//insert contact display name using Data.CONTENT_URI
contentProviderOperations.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0).withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,nameofcontact ).build());
//insert mobile number using Data.CONTENT_URI
contentProviderOperations.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0).withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, numberofcontact).withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE).build());
try {
//apply the changes
getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().
applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, contentProviderOperations);
} catch (RemoteException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: Inside `onCreate()` after `setContentView()`.

Comment: you can't call findviewbyid in static way, you must put the code inside the onCreate call

Comment: Thank you all for your help on this. I marked Ramesh Kumar as correct because really it was nice and clear and literally just copied and pasted his code to solve error. And now, to face all those other bugs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct way:

```
 EditText nameofcontact;
    EditText numberofcontact;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createButton);
nameofcontact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextname);
numberofcontact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextname);

}
```

when onCreate call then you can initialize your views. outside of method views can not be initialize because they could not find the context.

Answer (score 1):

Correct answers have been suggested already in terms of where you should move your EditText initialization code. Specifically, You could change your code into something like this below (copy and paste, test it and let us know if it works):
package com.example.chris.addnewcontact;

```
import android.content.ContentProviderOperation;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.OperationApplicationException;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public String contactname;
public String contactnumber;

//the lines below are giving me null pointer exception error.

EditText nameofcontact ;
EditText numberofcontact;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createButton);
 nameofcontact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextname);
 numberofcontact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextname);

}

public void createButton(View view) {

contactname = nameofcontact.getText().toString();
contactnumber = numberofcontact.getText().toString();

Log.d("test","yes, button is working");
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> contentProviderOperations = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
//insert raw contact using RawContacts.CONTENT_URI
contentProviderOperations.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
.withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null).withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null).build());
//insert contact display name using Data.CONTENT_URI
contentProviderOperations.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0).withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,nameofcontact ).build());
//insert mobile number using Data.CONTENT_URI
contentProviderOperations.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0).withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, numberofcontact).withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE).build());
try {
   //apply the changes
   getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().
   applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, contentProviderOperations);
} catch (RemoteException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
} catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best place would be in `onCreate` after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`, since this is where you add your views. When they are added you can look them up.

Adding those `findViewById` in your class itself will try looking them up when the activity is created—it is empty at this point, which is why your edit texts remain `null`.

Answer (score 0):

In the `onCreate()` method of your activity. 
But you can declare variables on the start of an activity.

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like your not instantiating of your edit text fields is not happening in the onCreate method like it should. Keep the declaration of those EditText out of the method if you would like them to remain global but move the instantation of those objects into the body of the onCreate method..

Also, use 2 different EditText items from your xml file for instantiating.